# How can i get my Toast Notification from outside the application?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, push-notification, mpns

Hi i got stuck with this problem, i can't find out how to get Toast notification from outside the application, i cant get it from inside like this :

```
private void ToastNotificationReceived(NotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        //liste_notifications.Items.Add("Toast : " + e.Collection["wp:Text1"]);
        if (e.Collection["wp:Text1"].Contains("Client"))
        {
            ClientNotification cn = new ClientNotification();
            cn.FromWho = e.Collection["wp:Text1"].Substring(6, 6);
            cn.Notification = e.Collection["wp:Text1"].Substring(12);
            cn.Date = DateTime.Now;
            ClientItems.Add(cn);
            PersistData();
        }
```

but i don't have a clue how to do it from outside. 
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Toast notification appears on top of the screen and no code/events are executed inside of your application

Comment: For exemple i push notification from my Desktop application to my Windows Phone application this toast notification have a username i need to get that username, how can i do that?

Comment: Only if application is already running, or download `username` later when application is launched next time

Comment: If you want to send user specific notifications, you have to store this informations with the phonechannel url at your registering service and use them to build the message you send to the microsoft service.